# React Native Navigator bug when transitioning between two pages

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a React Native Navigator on iOS as follows:

```
var SCREEN_WIDTH = require('Dimensions').get('window').width;
var BaseConfig = Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight;

var CustomLeftToRightGesture = Object.assign({}, BaseConfig.gestures.pop, {
   // Make it snap back really quickly after canceling pop
   snapVelocity: 8,
   // Make it so we can drag anywhere on the screen
   edgeHitWidth: SCREEN_WIDTH,
});

var CustomSceneConfig = Object.assign({}, BaseConfig, {
   // A very tighly wound spring will make this transition fast
   springTension: 100,
   springFriction: 10,
   // Use our custom gesture defined above
   gestures: {
   pop: CustomLeftToRightGesture,
   }
});
```

It all works fine when I push and pop. But when I actually try to pop by swiping the page to left and almost at the same time I swipe the page to right, I can see both pages in one page while both are transparent after releasing my finger.

I have this problem even with a non-custom animation for navigator. 
Is this a React Native bug in navigator or I am doing something wrong?